# Android: Get Pictures from Camera - be careful

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Lately i had written an android application that required to take a picture from the build in camera and get it back in my application. I used one of the many tutorials that are out there and everything worked fine. But then i tested it on a different device and nothing worked at all. There seems to be an problem, so how do i make sure i can take pics on every device? (See my answer, this is more like a tutorial)

Answer (score 5):

I used one of the many tutorials that are out there and everything worked fine. But then i tested it on a different device and nothing worked at all. At first i was very suprised but then i decided to go deeper into this topic. And i realized that a lot of these tutorials can cause a big problem. So i decided to share my experience with you.

Let me start with a common approch most of the tutorials are using.

At first you choose a requestID something like that:

```
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337;
```

Then you create an Intent and start the camera Activity

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

To get the Picture back you use the onActivityResult function and read the picture out of the received intent data

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        // do something like
       Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    }
}
```

Looks good doesn't it? Well it works but now comes the tricky part.

**As written in the android documentation the intent data will only return a sacled down or lets say small version of the taken photo and some devices doesn't return anything at all! It may even happen that the data isn't null but you get a "Failure delivering result ResultInfo" exception.**

So what now? The solution for this is quite simple. You just tell the Camera to save the picture to SD Card and return a URI to this file. Below, i will show you the edited code from above.

We create a static requestID **and** a URI

```
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337;
private static Uri outputFileUri;
```

We than create the camera activity, but this time we pass a additional parameter (our URI)

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

And now to handle the image we use the same method as above but instead of using the intent data we use our URI

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // do something to get the bitmap from the uri for example
          Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), outputFileUri);
}
```

With this solution you can make sure that you get a picture on every device. But be careful since you get a full scale bitmap it might be necessary to scale the bitmap down to avoid out of memory errors. If you don't want to keep the pic saved on the users SD Card simply delete that file.

Thanks for reading!